# How to 'enter' or add a carriage return in an <expr> mapping

Tags: vimrc

In the following `nnoremap`:

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>3 ToggleColors()
func ToggleColors()
    if g:colors_name == "OceanicNext"
        return ":colorscheme TextMate"
    else
        return ":colorscheme OceanicNext"
endfunc
```

I am able to get the function to return the proper command to 'enter', however, I have to actually press <kbd>return</kbd> for it to run. If I try entering either:

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>3 ToggleColors()<CR>
```

I get:

> E15: Invalid expression: ToggleColors() ^M

Or if I try doing:

```
return ":colorscheme TextMate <CR>"
```

It enters a literal  and doesn't actually hit enter:

What would be the proper way to 'hit enter' at the end of the mapping so I don't have to do it manually?

Comment: Maybe add `<cr>` to in the return value directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the key code can be input and written into a file directly.

So `let foo = 'Foo`<kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>`Bar'` looks like `let foo = 'Foo^MBar'`

But usually people want their sources do not contain control codes. So some sort of run-time substitution is preferred.

To put key code into a string in runtime one normally needs a backslash:

```
let foo = "Foo\<CR>Bar"
```

Note double quotes to allow string preprocessing.

When it's a part of a `:map` command, the substitution is made while reading a command before expression evaluation, so backslash is not needed:

```
nnoremap <A-X> :xit<CR>
```

or

```
nnoremap <expr><A-X> ':xit<CR>'
```

does not make a big difference.

If you want to stop such early expansion use `<lt>`:

```
nnoremap <expr><A-X> ":xit\<lt>CR>"
```

This one produces the same result as the previous. The expression is first expanded into `":xit\<CR>"` (while reading the command) and then into `':xit^M'` (while executing mapping).

Comment: oh, awesome, that makes it easy just adding in the actual (control) characters itself, so `^M` to simulate enter.

Comment: @David542 This is how mappings work: they are stored as real key codes. This is why you normally needs `-nore-` thing to disable recursive interpretation.